# How to unlock orientation just for one controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, screen-orientation

How can I unlock orientation just for one controller? I allowed just one - portrait - mode for whole my application, but just in one I need a landscape mode. For this I tried the next snippet:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool{
    return false
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}
```

but it doesn't help me. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can't unlock the rotation for one. You have to lock the rotation for all the others. Allow all the rotations you want and then lock down all the ones you want to not rotate.

Answer (score 2):

In Appdelegate define a var :

```
import UIKit
var isViewAppeared = false
```

now in Appdelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if isViewAppeared{
      return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    }
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
  }
```

Now in `ViewController` where you want landscape:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    isViewAppeared = true

  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    isViewAppeared = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
      let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
      UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    })

  }
```

Comment: can I rotate my orientation back to portrait in viewDisappear func? How can I do it?

Comment: i have already set that it will rotate to `Portrait` on `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

**enable** the desired orientations in the General Info Screen

in each `ViewController.swift`

- **override** the autorotation function with either true or false (**true** for the one that should rotate, **false** for the others)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: `enable the desired orientations in the General Info Screen in each ViewController.swift` how? Sorry, I did not understand you

Comment: but I do not want enable rotation, I want for all enable JUST portrait mode and just for the one enable landscape mode

Comment: in order to that you have to enable it

Comment: can I rotate my orientation back to portrait in viewDisappear func? How can I do it? Force rotate